# Stub a global function with karma and sinon

Tags: karma-runner, sinon, stub

I tried to stub a global function with karma and sinon. I have this functions

```
// lib/hello.js
var hello = function () {
  return 'hello';
};

var throwFunction = function () {
  throw 'throwFunction was called';
};

var callThrowFunction = function (arg) {
  throwFunction(arg);
};
```

and this test

```
// test/test_lib.js
describe('test lib', function () {

  it('test hello', function () {
    assert.strictEqual(hello(), 'hello');
  });

  it('throwFunction', function () {
    var stubFunction = sinon.stub(window, 'throwFunction');

    window.throwFunction();

    assert(stubFunction.called);

    stubFunction.restore();
  });

  it('callThrowFunction', function () {
    var stubFunction = sinon.stub(window, 'throwFunction');

    window.callThrowFunction('some arg');

    stubFunction.restore();
  });
});
```

When I call to karma, the first two tests run ok, but in the third I can't stub the function `throwFunction` and the `throw` is called.

```
karma start --single-run --reporters=spec

  test lib
    ✓ test hello
    ✓ throwFunction
    ✗ callThrowFunction
    the string "throwFunction was called" was thrown, throw an Error :)


PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 3 (1 FAILED) (0.019 secs / 0.007 secs)
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 2 SUCCESS


1) callThrowFunction
     test lib
     the string "throwFunction was called" was thrown, throw an Error :)
```